# Display emacs from linux (ubuntu) on Mac

Tags: display, ubuntu, mac

I'm SSHing from my macbook into an ubuntu server. I have emacs installed in both places.

So far I've found 3  ways to deal with this, and none of them are optimal:

1. run emacs on the ubuntu in the terminal window. This doesn't let me have multiple frames easily.
2. Run emacs on my mac and access files non-locally through ssh. This is slow (although I have not confirmed that it's actually slower than other options, I guess)
3. Run an X11 emulator on my mac and use X display forwarding. This seems like a pain, but I'll do it if it's considered the best way.

Is there another option? I'm probably going to run with option 2 until it sufficiently annoys me, I guess.

Comment: In method 2, when you say "access files non-locally through ssh", I presume you are talking about [`tramp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/)?

Comment: @nickD that is correct

Comment: Option 4: use a remote desktop solution such as VNC,Nomachine,x2go,xpra..., which is what I do (but the machines in question are literally 50 cm apart)

Comment: I also sometimes use a variant of Option 1: ssh into Linux, then either have multiple terminal frames (C-x 5 2), or run under tmux and run emacslient multiple times in multiple tmux windows

Comment: option 5. use modern version control and push/pull/sync as necessary

Comment: So, every time I make a change, I have to push, from my laptop, then pull on the ubuntu machine? that seems excessive, when tramp works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

- 2a Use `tramp` with the scp method instead of ssh, it's much faster
- 4 Mount the remote filesystem locally using some suitable protocol (e.g. smb, nfs, sshfs, etc.)